# Does the Falcon 9 stage 1 have cold gas thrusters near the bottom?

Tags: falcon-9, rcs

I've seen the cold gas thruster pods on the interstage of Falcon 9, and I know that stage 2 has them too, even if there seem to be zero pictures of them on the web (they're the only means of roll control in stage 2).

But I was surprised today when I saw video of what seems to be cold gas thrusters firing... from the bottom of stage 1! I was not expecting this.

You can see them at 8:49 in [this video](https://youtu.be/T3_Voh7NgDE?t=302).

Am I misinterpreting the white jets seen in the video? I've pored over pictures of Falcon 9 and never once did I see cold gas thruster pods near the bottom---though I also never found the pods that reportedly exist in stage 2, so I may just be very good at not finding these things.